# Spring MVC: Error 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This seems to be a common issue. I have gone all the answers given in SO but could not make it work.
I am trying to integrate Spring MVC+Freemarker in already existing web application. It works fine for the `GET` request and Freemarker Template reads java object provided by Controller without any issue.
But Form submission is not able to hit Controller method. Finally I made log4j work. Here is the error I am getting:
**Error**

```
    HandlerMethod details: 
    Controller [application.entry.controller.UserController]
    Method [public void application.entry.controller.UserController.handleSave(java.lang.String)]

    org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: 
Required String parameter 'action' is not present
```

**Freemarker:**

```
<form method="POST" action="save.html">
  ------------
  <input type="submit" class="btnnew" name="saveWithoutValidation" value="Save Without Validation"></input>
  <input type="submit" class="btnnew" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

context-root is **PORTAL**.
**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
      <property name="cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="prefix" value=""/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void handleSave(@RequestParam String action){

        if( action.equals("submit") ){
            System.out.println("Damn! You clicked submit");
        }
        else if( action.equals("saveWithoutValidation") ){
           System.out.println("Sweet! You want no string attached.");
        }

    }
```

For logs I have tried to add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to my existing log4j.properties but it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also had this issue and my solution was different, so adding here for any who have similar problem.

My controller had:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setPassword(Model model, @RequestParameter SetPassword setPassword) {
    ...
}
```

The issue was that this should be **`@ModelAttribute`** for the object, not `@RequestParameter`. The error message for this is the same as you describe in your question.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setPassword(Model model, @ModelAttribute SetPassword setPassword) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` will work because it also binds the request to the annotated target. `@RequestParam` however is a better fit for binding request parameters individually.

Answer (score 12):

The `@RequestParam String action` suggests there is a parameter present within the request with the name *action* which is absent in your form. You must either:

1. Submit a parameter named *value* e.g. `<input name="action" />`
2. Set the required parameter to `false` within the `@RequestParam` e.g. `@RequestParam(required=false)`

Answer (score 9):

Another possible cause is to have the wrong order of RequestMapping attributes.
As spring doc says:

> An @RequestMapping handler method can have a very flexible signatures.
>   The supported method arguments and return values are described in the
>   following section. **Most arguments can be used in arbitrary order with
>   the only exception of BindingResult arguments**. This is described in
>   the next section.

If you scroll down the doc, you will see that the BindingResult has to be immediatelly after the model attribute, since we can have multiple model objects per request and thus multiple bindings

> The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object
>   that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have
>   more than one model object and Spring will create a separate
>   BindingResult instance for each of them so the following sample won’t
>   work:

Here are two examples:

> Invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute.
>
> @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) public String
>   processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, Model model,
>   BindingResult result) { ... } Note, that there is a Model parameter in
>   between Pet and BindingResult. To get this working you have to reorder
>   the parameters as follows:
>
> @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) public String
>   processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result,
>   Model model) { ... }

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue and found that a few fields like Date were not getting a concrete value, once given the values things worked fine. Please make sure you do not have date or any other field present on the form which needs a concrete value.

Comment: That was the problem for me.  I just assumed Spring would handle an empty value for date fields, but I guess not?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error:

```
Required String parameter 'action' is not present
```

There needs to be a request parameter named `action` present in the request for Spring to map the request to your handler `handleSave`.

The HTML that you pasted shows no such parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Controller trying to find the "action" value in bean but according to your example you have not set any bean name of "action".
try to do name="action".
@RequestParam always find in the bean class.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the lack of `BindingResult` parameter after my model attribute.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sign-up", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo
                                HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                HttpSession httpSession) { ... }
```

After I added `BindingResult` my controller became

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sign-up", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute  UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo, BindingResult bindingResult,
                                HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                HttpSession httpSession) { ..}
```

Check answer @sashok_bg 
@sashko_bg Mersi mnogo

Answer (score 0):

Your request mapping is `/save`, but your POST is to `/save.html`. Changing the POST to `/save` should fix it.

Comment: Actually `/save` gave me 404. I did tried with `<form method="POST" action="save">` but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep your

```
<form method="POST" action="XYZ">

@RequestMapping(value="/XYZ", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void handleSave(@RequestParam String action){
```

Your form action attribute value must match to value of `@RequestMapping`, So that Spring MVC can resolve it.

Also, as you told it is giving 404 after changing, for this, can you please check whether control is entering inside `handleSave()` method.

I think, as you are not returning any thing from `handleSave()` method, you have to look at it.

if it still not work, can you please post your spring logs.

Also, make sure that your request should come like

```
/PORTAL/save
```

if there is anything between like `PORTAL/jsp/save` the mention in `@RequestMapping(value="/jsp/save")`

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the cause of error, that will help others who will face similar error.

Comment: I have added the exception in my question. But have no idea on how to resolve it.

Comment: I think exception is caused due to your Parameter taken by handleSave(@RequestParam String action) method. there is no mapping found in html form for parameter in handleSave method. try runnning app by changing handleSave method to handleSave(){ // your code}

Comment: OK. Then how would I get all the form values and which button got clicked?

Comment: one way you can do is  public void handleSave(HttpServletRequest request) {String data1 = request.getParameter("your_html_element_name");}

Answer (score 0):

```
@CookieValue(value="abc",required=true) String m
```

when I changed required from  true to false,it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Add BindingResult  parameter in your method. For reference please my code below.

`save(@ModelAttribute Employee employee,BindingResult bindingResult)`