# why spring mvc can't supply bad request error message when use jetty?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I found a very strange phenomenon when use spring boot, at first I used jetty, there is a PUT request, it's request body is a JSON, if client input an unnecessary property, e.g. "foo":"bar", Spring mvc does not have any error messge, in swagger ui there is only :

[image]

but if I changed to tomcat,Spring mvc will return a clear exception, like this:

```
{
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Could not read document: Unrecognized field \"foo\" (class com.), not marked as ignorable (......)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@51c5845a; line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: \"foo\"]); 
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
}
```

why spring mvc can't supply error message when use jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Error `400 Bad Request` is unique, as it means the request itself is bad.  So bad, that not even the container knows what is it, or can even recognize it as a HTTP Request.

If the container can't recognize it as an HTTP Request, then how will it know what context (webapp) to send the request (that doesn't exist) to in order for the Error Handling logic to process it?

Comment: if this is a POST request, with jetty, the output is:{
  "code": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
} in this case, it has response body, but still have not clear error messge.

Comment: General advice is that all bets are off with an Http Response Status 400 Bad Request.  The request was so bad, that something on the server didn't recognize it, or know what to do with it.  So bad, that even clear messages are not often possible.

Comment: That is not actually true, when using Spring MVC. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC sometimes behaves very strange, I had a spring MVC error 400 when posting a form, the problem that made MVC return 400 bad request was actually the lack of `BindingResult`. Please see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792274/spring-mvc-error-400-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect).

There are many reasons why spring can return 400 Bad request.

Comment: The OP gets no body content on their error 400, if this was returned from Spring, then there would be body content.  Since its empty, its likely from the Container.