# Deploy Spring application using Gradle build on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, gradle

I am new to spring and Gradle. I am trying to Deploy Spring application using Gradle build on Tomcat server. I am able to generate a war file but i do not have web.xml file for mapping servlets and neither I have mapping servlets. I have a main class and configuration class.

So, In order to deploy my application on tomcat what all I need to do ? I couldn't find a proper end to end article for this. I went through this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html (This article is mostly covering maven repository/plugin not the Gradle part) and am able to generate only the war file. As I do not have any web.xml I am not sure how to deploy this. Can anyone please help me with this.

```
   buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "" }
    mavenLocal()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-     plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")

}
    }

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
 apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


 apply plugin: 'war'

war {
baseName = 'abc-service'
version =  '0.1.0'
}


 repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "" }
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
compile("org.springframework:spring-oxm")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
compile("com.h2database:h2")
compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16")
compile("com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.4.1")

compile("commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4")
compile("com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.5")
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat");
testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.1'
 }
```

Here is sample code for my user controller:

```
 @Controller
public class AuthenticationController {
@RequestMapping(value =    "/authentication/userLogin")
 public @ResponseBody
 ResponseEntity<Object> user(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true)      String username,
@RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password,
HttpServletResponse response) {
 return this.authenticationService.loginUser(username, password);
 } 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/authentication/register")
public @ResponseBody
 Response register(@RequestBody String jsonRequest,
HttpServletResponse response) {
 AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
 Response registerResponse =     authenticationService.registerUser(jsonRequest);
 return registerResponse;
 }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application is good to go as it is, as long as you have controller defined. One of the best feature of Spring-boot is, it does most of the dirty work for you. You have to define the controller and url path as annotation using `@RequestMapping("/your-path")`. Also, annotate the class with `@RestController`. If you could give the url for this application code, I will be able to look into it further if it has all necessary definitions. Besides, I would recommend a few changes.

Update spring-boot-version to latest 1.3.5

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
```

Update Gradle Version

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {

    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

Update other dependencies as well. Then call the following commands.

```
gradle wrapper
./gradlew clean build
```

The first line will download set your project to run with Gradle version 2.13 and download it to a temporary directory irrespective of the Gradle version installed in your computer. Second line will build your project using that downloaded latest Gradle. Then check your `<project-root-directory>/build/libs` directory. You will see `abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` file. Just pick up that war and deploy it in you Tomcat server.

If you are deploying the war file to Tomcat, you should add the application build name to URL to access your mappings, since Tomcat use the filename of the war file for context path ([check here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4682)). Eg: `localhost:8080/abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/your-mapping/`. You can specify how your war should named using baseName property. For example, you can get rid of the version number if you don't want it in your application URL.

```
war {
   baseName = 'abc-service'
}
```

Or you can simply rename your war file to whatever the root context you want after Gradle build before copying into Tomcat.

Another feature I like about spring-boot is, you don't need an external Tomcat server for deploying spring-boot application. It already has an embedded Tomcat server. To take advantage of this feature, you build you application as a jar file, and run as java application. To do so, first, get rid of the line `apply plugin: 'war'`. And change your war configuration to jar configuration.

```
jar {
   baseName = 'abc-service'
   version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

And run this as jar file.

```
java -jar <project-root-directory>/build/libs/abc-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If you are using jar file, you can simply use whatever your mapping you specified. Eg: `localhost:8080/your-mapping`.

Based on your controller your REST call for the user (authenticating) should be `localhost:8080/authentication/userLogin?username=<user-name>&password=<pass-word>`. If you miss either user name or password you will get the error since they are required (`required=true`) fields based on your code. Also your register method should be configured as post and you should pass a request body.You can use Advanced REST Client/ POSTMAN Google Chrome extension to make post request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authentication/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response register(@RequestBody String jsonRequest,
   HttpServletResponse response) {
  AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
  Response registerResponse =   authenticationService.registerUser(jsonRequest);
  return registerResponse;
}}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for your response.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your prompt response. I do have the '@RequestMapping' and '@Controller' in my controller class.
Right now, I am using the jar file that you mentioned. But I want something (like WAR) so that I can drop
into tomcat web container in order to host my application.
My questions are:
• Do we really need web.xml file? If so, Is there any sample for web.xml file for this?
• Is it possible to host jar file? If so How? As i already generated a war file i am looking for web.xml file something similar that java EE applications contain.

Comment: Without the web.xml file, I just tried to drop the WAR file into Tomcat container, but it threw an exception saying '404 connection refused'
Thank you. 

Comment: Did you add your application name after base URL. Like, `localhost:8080/abc-service/your-mapping/`. Also, don't forget the trailing '/'. I don't have a Gradle project with me right now, I tested a Maven project without web.xml. It works fine. Checkout the answers for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34506712/1257729)

Comment: If you are running as jar, you don't need the application name, just do `localhost:8080/your-mapping`

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the changes on the comments. Check it out.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I tried again having the war file and URL. My URL is [link](http://localhost:8080/lottery-service-0.1.0) but tomcat is throwing an error stating " The requested resource is not available". Once i am giving the path for the requested mapping parameters (for ex [link](http://localhost:8080/lottery-service-0.1.0/my-maping)) the error is "Required String parameter 'xxxxx' is not present. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." Please let me know your inputs. what could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Dude, unless give me more information (like your code, or you controller, application.properties file etc.), I am not sure I could help you any further. Could you please create a repository in Github or somewhere and post the link. Or if you are trying to replicate a code already in Github, can you post the link here?

Comment: One thing I could think of it though, the method you are mapping your request to, might need some parameter which you are not passing through your request. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792274/spring-mvc-error-400-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have many controller classes like for authenticating the user, payment controller etc.. I am posting the sample codes by editing in the question

Comment: Please let me know your update. Can you please provide a sample end to end application which generates war file using gradle? It would be of great help.Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer. You should Google for sample application or check at Github.

Comment: Hey Thank you.. that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your spring boot Application class is extending SpringBootServletInitializer. if your Application class is not extending SpringBootServletInitializer, then running the tomcat server using catalina.sh run script will not work. You need to use java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app_name.war.